# Android: Creating a custom component programmatically does not reflect the style applied

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Created a custom button which extends AppCompatButton. The following are the constructors used:

```
public CustomButton(Context context)
{
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    this(context, attrs, R.style.customStyle);
}

public CustomButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```

Constructing CustomButton through XML works fine. However, when constructed in Java, it does not reflect the customStyle properties. Tried debugging the code. Though it passes through the second constructor doesn't take up the properties.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a ContextThemeWrapper object when creating CustomButton programmatically.

In activity file:

CustomButton customButton = new CustomButton( new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.customStyle));